# Can somebody convert this javascript in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to add event listener in my react project. My browser opens the file which i drag and drop in the dropzone. I want to prevent that from happening. I did not found any solution for that except this code. I need a typerscript solution for this

```
window.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
 },false);
window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
   e = e || event;
   e.preventDefault();
},false);
```

Comment: That **is** a typescript solution.

Comment: it gives me this error  (method) Chat.addEventListener(: any): any
'addEventListener', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.ts(7010)

Comment: Change `function(e){` to `(e: DragEvent): void => {`

Answer (score 2):

There're always more than one way to convert JavaScript to Typescript as well as there're many ways to convert TypeScript to JavaScipt. That's because these are not just some interchangeable formats but rather syntaxes one build over another.

Still, you can make your code mode TypeScripttish:

```
window.addEventListener('dragover', (e: DragEvent) => (e || event).preventDefault(), false);

window.addEventListener('drop', (e: DragEvent) => (e || event).preventDefault(), false);
```

provided you have some variable `event` defined before you use the code above.